# XAMPP-File upload error

Tags: php, laravel-5, xampp

I used a form to upload a image file(about 200k). And moved it to a specified folder in back-end. But when I have open this file in this folder,it's not a image file,its size were just 45 bytes. And I try edit it,the file contents were "XAMPP/xamppfile/temp/phpdBLLad" instead of binary code. Just save a ['tmp_name'] in my file.

front-end:

```
<form action="/photos" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class = 'col-md-12 red_line2' style = "height:40px;width:30%; color:black">

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
        <input type = "hidden" name = 'album_id' value = '{{$album->id}}'>
        <input id = 'addimg' name = 'myimage' type="file" multiple style="display:none" />
        <button type = 'button' id = 'fileUpload' class="btn btn-link btn-lg"  data-target="#image_preview" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            <span class="fa fa-camera"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-lg" >
            <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-lg" >
            <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
    <div class = 'col-md-12'>
        <div class = "extraspace-small"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'col-md-12'>
        <div class = "collapse" id = "image_preview">
        <div class = 'pull-right myfloater'>
            <button id = "upload" type = "submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary vcenter">
                UPLOAD
            </button>
            <button id = "cancle_upload" type = "button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger vcenter">
                CANCLE
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class = "well mywell" id = 'preview_container'>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

back-end:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
      'album_id'=>'required',
      'myimage'=>'required|image'
    );        

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);        

    if($validator->fails()){
        var_dump($validator->errors());
    }

    $data = $request->only('album_id','myimage');
    $destinationPath = 'albums/';
    $file = $request->file('myimage');
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    Storage::put($destinationPath.$filename, $data['myimage']);
    $album = Images::create(array(
      'image' => $filename,
      'album_id' => $request->album_id,
    ));

    return redirect('photos/'.$request->album_id);//,['id'=>$album->id]
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code so someone can perhaps identify the problem?